# Invariance of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, invariance

Suppose that instead of rectangular coordinates $x $ and $y $, we introduce curvilinear coordinates  $u $ and $v $, where
$$x = x(u,v) \space \text { and } \space y = y (u,v) $$
And
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
        x_u & x_v \\
        y_u & y_v \\
        \end{vmatrix} \ne 0$$
Then the curve given by $y=y (x) $ corresponds to the curve given by some equation $v = v (u) $ in the $uv $-plane. The functional
$$J [y] = \int_a^b F (x,y,y')dx $$ becomes
$$J_1 [v] = \int_{a_1}^{b_1} F [x (u,v),y (u,v), \frac {y_u + y_v v'}{x_u+x_v v'}] (x_u+x_v v')du = \int_{a_1}^{b_1} F_1[u,v,v']du$$

Let $\Delta \sigma$ denote the area bounded by the curves $y = y(x)$ and $y = y(x)+h(x)$ and $\Delta \sigma_1$ denote the area bounded between the curves $v = v(u)$ and $v = v(u)+\eta(u)$

As my book states, "as $\Delta \sigma, \Delta \sigma_1 \to 0$, the ratio $\Delta \sigma / \Delta \sigma_1 $ approaches the Jacobian, which is non zero by hypothesis. Thus
$$\lim_{\Delta \sigma \to 0} \frac{J[y+h]-J[y]}{\Delta \sigma}  = 0$$
Implies
$$\lim_{\Delta \sigma_1 \to 0} \frac{J[v+\eta]-J[v]}{\Delta \sigma_1}  = 0$$

So that $v$ is extremal if and only if $y$ is extremal."

> I don't understand how the ratio of areas approaching a non-zero number in the limit that they go to zero implies that
>
> $$\lim_{\Delta \sigma_1 \to 0} \frac{J[v+\eta]-J[v]}{\Delta \sigma_1}  = 0$$
>   If
>   $$\lim_{\Delta \sigma \to 0} \frac{J[y+h]-J[y]}{\Delta \sigma}  = 0$$

If anyone has notational questions, let me know and I will clarify

Comment: Why not mention that the textbook is Gelfand/Fomin "Calculus of Variations", p.29-30? It is easier to understand the proof when it is embedded in what the authors had defined and derived before. -- There are also some derivations of the invariance around in Physics SE.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I find the derivation slightly clearer when variations are written as $w(x) = \hat{w} (x) + \epsilon  \beta(x)$ and the limits are performed with respect to the variation parameter $\epsilon$, not $\Delta \sigma$, for example as done in http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/ClassicalMechanics/CMCoordinateinvarianceofEulerLagrange.pdf.

Anyhow, I believe the point made by your textbook could be explained as follows.

If   $$ \frac{ \Delta \sigma}{\Delta_1 \sigma } \to I $$ ($I$ standing for the Jacobian)  as $\Delta \sigma, \Delta_1 \sigma \to 0$, one could write to first order
$$ lim_{\Delta \sigma \to 0} \frac{J[y + h] – J[y]}{\Delta \sigma} =   lim_{\Delta_1 \sigma \to 0} \frac{J[y + h] – J[y]}{I \Delta_1 \sigma} = \frac{1}{I} lim_{\Delta_1 \sigma \to 0} \frac{J[y + h] – J[y]}{\Delta_1 \sigma} $$
The action at the numerator is invariant upon coordinate changes, so the fact that $I \neq 0$ and that the first limit equals $0$ implies the conclusion.

Comment: @nfinitylord, if you let us know what part of the answer in unclear or unsatisfactory, I will be glad to further elaborate upon it.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. What confuses me is how to get the numerator in terms of $J[v]$ and $J[v + \eta]$. It is not obvious to me that the numerator is invariant. To be honest, i'm not exactly sure how the ratio of areas converges to the Jacobian either (though it does appeal to intuition to an extent)

Comment: I might manage to edit my answer later. For now, let me just add a brief Point: the fact that the ratios of the areas converges to the Jacobian could maybe be better  understood by thinking at the integration by substitution formula: the function of the Jacobian in that context is exactly to Keep track of the area measure change when switching variables.

Comment: With reference to the invariance of the Action, the link I provided you with has a detailed proof. I would be glad to comment on any step that might be confusing. From the physical point of view, this expresses the intuitively appealing that integrating a Lagrangian (difference between kinetic and potential energy) along a curve, gives you a result  that is indipendent of the curve paramatrization (fully equivalently to how the length of a curve does not depend on the parametrisation chosen to represent it).

Comment: @infinitylord, the source of some difficulties is also related to terminology. When it is said that the ratio of the areas converges to the Jacobian, I believe it is meant "the determinant of the Jacobian matrix", exactly like in integrals by substitution. The ratio of the area does not of course converge to the Jacobian matrix.